# Querying a reg key with a space in it

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will determine if a PC has a specific MS Hotfix installed, and is running XP SP2, not SP3.

I so far cannot even get the first part of this to work, due to the reg key having a space in "Windows XP"

The batch file so far:

```
@echo off

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Windows XP\SP3\KB932823-v3\>nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto :nohotfix
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto :hotfixpresent


:Hotfixpresent
@echo hot fix is present
pause

:nohotfix
@echo No hotfix is present
pause
```

the gotos are just placeholders for future code at present.

I get the following error at the moment - Error: Invalid command-line parameters

Anyone got an idea how I can get around this?

thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 7):

Use quotes (`"`) around key path.

e.g.

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Windows XP\SP3\KB932823-v3">nul
```

Comment: This only results in the following error message - Error: The system was unable to find the specificed registry key or value - this does not let the rest of the script complete

Comment: Then the key was not present. Mostly, it means that the particular update was not installed. Did it not set the errorlevel variable?

Comment: yeah it did not set the errorlevel, so the rest of the script cannot continue - any ideas? Thanks for taking the itme to look at this for me.

Comment: Also your syntax for `reg query` is wrong. check `reg query /?` output. You need to specify `/ve` or `/v value_name`.

Comment: Windows 8 reg.exe sets the errorlevel if the key is missing.  Double check that errorlevel.  @anishsane The /v /ve isn't needed in Win 8 either.  I suspect that the XP version will work the same way - it'll return whatever is in the key.  **EDIT**  I confirmed that XP's reg.exe (SP3) works the same way.